# Very long database access times after publishing asp.net app to server

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a very simple asp.net application which reads a database table and displays some info about the records on a page load.  Currently the demo database only contains 2 records for testing.  I am using entity framework and when running locally the page load is very quick << 1sec
After I deploy the application to a server from the trace I have put in around the calls, looping over the ObjectSet takes around 45 seconds per record.  I am struggling to work out what is causing this delay.

update:

This is using MS SQL

I put trace outputs around every line of code and only the 1 line has any significant delay:

```
// this isnt fancy just extending ObjectContext
var databaseEntities = new myTableDatabaseEntities(); 
var myClassObjectSet = databaseEntities.MyRecords;

// This following call takes 44seconds per record in the database 
// so with my 2 records takes 88 seconds
var myRecords = myClassObjectset.ToList();
```

Comment: What's the query? Which DB server (assuming MS SQL, but...)?

Comment: Nothing obvious here. What happens inside `databaseEntities.MyRecords`? Since some evaluations result in lazy loading your problem could be there.

Comment: Are other non-entity based queries performing this slowly also? You have changed environments, are you on a shared server? It could be that the server is under high load.

Comment: It makes sense that the delay occurs when you call the ToList() method since that is when the execution of the query actually takes place. Have you tried running other queries to see if they also run slow? Could it be a slow connection between the web server and the sql server?

Comment: Ok, when I remove the need to authenticate from the web.config file by setting <allow users="*" /> the page load is as quick as it is locally.  So it does seem as this is a permissions issue somewhere, what I am confused about is that the original method does work it just takes 45 seconds or so per record - if the permissions were failing i wouldn't have expected to have gotten the results at all?!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it without your wrapper class `myTableDatabaseEntities`?  This will prove if it is something wrong in your wrapper class or not:

```
// var databaseEntities = new myTableDatabaseEntities();
var databaseEntities = new ObjectContext();
```

And then checking if it is still slow.